# BETWEEN two dates with functions SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, between

I would like to extract data from the 20th last month until now, but is it impossible to make functions when making a BETWEEN AND command?

```
WHERE ([dtUpdated] BETWEEN ((Year(Date()))-(Month(Date())-1)-20)
    AND (Date()))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateAdd` to subtract one month from today's date.  Here's an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
? Date()
8/15/2013 
? DateAdd("m", -1, Date())
7/15/2013
```

Then you can determine the `Year` and `Month` of that previous date.

```vb
? Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()))
 2013 
? Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()))
 7
```

So finally you can give `DateSerial` the `Year`, `Month`, and 20 as the day.

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())), _
    Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())), 20)
7/20/2013
```

In a query, try it like this ...

```vb
WHERE [dtUpdated] BETWEEN
    DateSerial(
        Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())),
        Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())),
        20)
    AND Date()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can see the logic but I get too few parameters. I guess the format has to be 2013-07-20 instead of 2013/07/20 or something. If I type in manually Between #2013-07-20# AND Date() it works as intented (EDIT: Ok it is working if I do it like this Date(Dateserial(.....)) AND Date()

Comment: `DateSerial` returns a Date/Time value, so format should not be an issue.  I just tested this query in Access 2007 and it worked without error: `SELECT *
FROM tblFoo
WHERE [datetime_field] BETWEEN
    DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())),
        Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date())),
        20)
    AND Date();`

Comment: "Too few parameters" often happens when something is misspelled in the SQL statement: a table or a field name; a function name or one of the function's arguments; or an SQL keyword.  Also you must use quotes around `m` in all those `DateAdd` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to make a date by just putting the numbers in a date format like 'yyyy-mm-dd', but really you are just subtracting a bunch of numbers (2013-3-5 = 2005) and so I'm guessing you are getting a type mismatch.

I think MS Access has a `DATEADD` function where you can build a date through arithmetic.

If you want since the 20th of last month it would be something like

1. Add -1 * current day number (subtract off days in current month)
2. Add -1 months (to get last month)
3. Add 20 days (get the 20th)

I think it would be something like this

```
DATEADD(d, 20, DATEADD(m, -1 * Month(Date()), DATEADD(d, -1 * Day(Date()), Date())))
```

This can be done with subsequent DATEADD calls

Comment: The syntax is *DateAdd(interval, number, date)* and *interval* must be a string expression.